# Implementing a Java server

Tags: java, server, client

My biggest problem is attempting to remove a client when the "disconnect" button is hit.  It doesn't work properly, and I'm not sure if my approach is best: sending out a list of all the current users to the clients.

Any major logic/coding flaws and any suggestions for improvement would also be welcome.

**Server class:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Server {
static ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<PrintWriter> outG = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();
static int port=4444;

// ip address: 192.168.0.104


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Collections.synchronizedList(users);
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.print("success");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: "+port);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        while(true){
            Thread thread = new Thread(new UserThread(serverSocket.accept()));
            thread.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    serverSocket.close();
}
}
```

**User Thread (when a client tries to connect):**

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class UserThread extends Server implements Runnable{
private Socket socket = null;
String message="";
String name="";
String id="";
public UserThread(Socket sock){
    this.socket=sock;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        addWriter(outG,out);
        boolean temp2=true;
        while(temp2){
            boolean temp3=true;
            String name = readIn(in,true);
            for(int i=0;i<getArraySize(users);i++){//trying to make sure that one client doesnt 
                if(getArray(users,i).equals(name)){//enter a name that another already typed in
                    sendOut(out,"no",true,false,false);
                    temp3=false;
                    i=getArraySize(users);
                }
            }
            if(temp3){
                sendOut(out,"yes",true,false,false);
                addArray(users,name);
                temp2=false;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<getWriterSize(outG);i++){//sending to all clients a list of all the clients
            sendOut(outG.get(i),"",false,true,false);
        }
        while (true) {
            readIn(in,false);
            if(name.equals("bye")){
                for(int i=0;i<getWriterSize(outG);i++){
                    sendOut(outG.get(i),"",false,true,false);
                }
                removeArray(users,id);
                removeoutG(outG,id);
                break;
            }
            int index=search(id);
            sendOut(outG.get(index),"",false,false,true);
            message=null;
            name=null;
            id=null;
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public int search(String name){
    for(int i=0;i<getArraySize(users);i++){
        if(getArray(users,i).equals(name)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public /*synchronized*/ void sendOut(PrintWriter out,String item,boolean init,boolean sendingNames,boolean sendingMessage){
    if(init){//not sure if i should syncronize??
        out.println(item);
        out.flush();
    }
    else if(sendingNames){
        out.println("~StOp");
        out.flush();
        out.println(users);
        out.flush();
    }
    else if(sendingMessage){
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
        out.println(name);
        out.flush();
        out.flush();
    }
}
public /*synchronized*/ String readIn(BufferedReader in, boolean one){
    if(one){
        try {
            return in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        try {
            message= in.readLine();
            name= in.readLine();
            id= in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}       
public /*synchronized*/ String getArray(ArrayList<String>users,int i){
    return users.get(i);
}
public /*synchronized*/ void removeArray(ArrayList<String>users,String name){
    users.remove(name);
}
public /*synchronized*/ void removeoutG(ArrayList<PrintWriter>users,String name){
    int index=search(name);
    outG.remove(index);
}

public /*synchronized*/ int getArraySize(ArrayList<String>users){
    return users.size();
}
public /*synchronized*/ int getWriterSize(ArrayList<PrintWriter>out){
    return out.size();
}
public /*synchronized*/ void addArray(ArrayList<String>users,String name){
    users.add(name);
}
public /*synchronized*/ void addReader(ArrayList<BufferedReader>inG,BufferedReader r){
    inG.add(r);
}
public /*synchronized*/ void addWriter(ArrayList<PrintWriter>outG,PrintWriter p){
    outG.add(p);
}
 }
```

Comment: This code could use much more advice; but you should implement all of @palacsint's suggestions first, to make other problems _operable_.

Answer (score 5):

(It's not a complete review, just a few random notes.)

1. `ArrayList<...>` reference types should be simply `List<...>`. See: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*

   ```
   private static List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
   ```
2. `Collections.synchronizedList()` does not modify the parameter. It returns a new lists which is synchronized, you should use its return value.
3. Instead of the `boolean` flag of the `readIn` method (which is hard to read, readers have to check the implementation to know what `true` and `false` means) I'd create two methods: a `readName` and (probably) a `readMessage`. Then it would be obvious what the called method does. See: Clean Code by Robert C. Martin, Flag Arguments, p41
4. Instead of modifying `i` (`i = getArraySize(users)`) to finish the loop you could break it:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < getArraySize(users); i++) {
       if (getArray(users, i).equals(name)) {
           sendOut(out, "no", true, false, false);
           temp3 = false;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Furthermore, you could replace the whole loop with the [`List.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method. The Java ecosystem is really big - if you find that you're writing something that could be useful for someone else too (like getting the index of an element from a list) it certainly has been written. Search for a few minutes. If JDK does not have a method for that Google Guava or Apache Commons probably has.
6. Comments like these are hard to modify:

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<getArraySize(users);i++){//trying to make sure that one client doesnt 
       if(getArray(users,i).equals(name)){//enter a name that another already typed in
   ```

   Placing them before the line are easier to maintain:

   ```
   //trying to make sure that one client doesnt enter a name that another already typed in
   for(int i=0;i<getArraySize(users);i++){
       if(getArray(users,i).equals(name)){
   ```

   Anyway, comments often could be function names and the commented code could be extracted out to these functions. References:

   - *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Bad Comments, p67*: *Don’t Use a Comment When You Can Use a Function or a Variable*.
   - *Refactoring* by *Martin Fowler*, *Chapter 3. Bad Smells in Code*, *Long Method*
7. Variable name like `temp2`, `temp3` are hard to understand. For example,`temp3` could be renamed to `userExists`, if I'm right. It explains the purpose and helps readers a lot.